# How to use lambda expressions to pass method as parameter

Tags: lambda

I'm developing a simple 2d game engine in Java for a university project right now and we are having major issues trying to figure out how we can have a method for the application programmer where he can send in a keycode, member and a member method in order for them to bind a specific key to a specific method.

We have a `Game` class that contains the most of the stuff relevant at this point and when we did a similar project in C++ we were able to create a method in the Game class that would take a `std::function` and keycode as a parameter (and the std function contains a member and a member function) and then just store those in a map and whenever the correct key was pressed we just called that `std::function` which performed the correct method on the correct object.

We've been searching a lot for a similar solutions in java and the only thing we can find is the use of lambda expressions but we haven't managed to find any decent guides that was helpful for our example. The questions is basically how we go about binding a specific key to a specific member and function if the structure looks like this:

the Game.java class contains a player object, and we want to be able to call a function in the Main-class that would work like this

```
 game.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_UP, player,jump())
```

The game class would then store these bindings in a structure of some sort where it can be iterated over and when up is pressed the `jump()` method will be invoked in player.

How do we go about doing this in Java and is there any easier way we can bind keys to methods without using lambdas?

Answer (score 0):

From what you said it seems that a Visitor pattern would be a useful way of looking at the problem, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm

Specifically, I would start with accepting an interface, that has an "action" method to do what you want exactly, similar to something like this:

```java
public interface GameKeyBoardAction {
    public void executeAction(Context cx)
}

public class JumpAction implements GameKeyBoardAction {
    public void executeAction(Context cx) {
        // ... do what's needed for the jump action
    }
}
```

then you can call it somewhere:

```
game.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_UP, player, new JumpAction())
```

also I would recommend using a `Map` implementation to look up the actions, either a simple HashMap or something from `java.util.concurrent.` or similar library

Comment: Thanks for the response! We managed to solve it using the Java 8 lambdas before we saw this answer but it seems like your suggestion is the old way to do it and now people mostly recommend using the lambas to save down as runnable as it makes the code a lot cleaner. We simply have a Map with an Integer as a key and then the runnable lambda as the value, works great so far!

Comment: Lambdas definitely work :) What you chose is just a matter of design preferences. Glad you found a solution.